# Bootstrap Center alert between images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to center an alert horizontally between 2 images... This is my code so far.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
    <img width="120" height="120" src="1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <span class="alert alert-success">
      Test
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img width="120" height="120" src="2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming I'm going to need a bit of custom css but not sure what...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code with 2 CSS custom classes for alert container and itself. I assumed your column height is 120px based on your image height.

The snippet below is not display correctly because smaller view-port. Please click to Full page on the right corner or copy to your local and test.

```css
.alert-middle-container {
  line-height: 120px;
}
.alert-middle {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center alert-middle-container">
      <span class="alert alert-success alert-middle">
                    Test
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to center an alert horizontally between 2 images...

It's because the width of the images is less than the width of the columns. You will see this if you paint the background for each column:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3" style="background: #9cf;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/c69/f9c/?text=1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background: #cf9;">
      <span class="alert alert-success">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background: #f9c;">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/69c/9cf/?text=2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the first solution is to add the `text-center` class to the `<div class="row">`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/c69/f9c/?text=1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span class="alert alert-success">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/69c/9cf/?text=2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second solution is to use one columns for all three objects:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <img class="pull-left" width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/c69/f9c/?text=1.png">
      <img class="pull-right" width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/69c/9cf/?text=2.png">
      <span class="alert alert-success">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. Don't forget to wrap row into container. The `row` class has negative margins and the `container` class compensates this peculiarity.

Answer (score 0):

*One other way is to use the Bootstrap classes :*

`text-center` and `center-block`

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/9UZ6sQgjX9

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <img class="center-block" width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/c69/f9c/?text=1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <span class="alert alert-success ">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="center-block" width="120" height="120" src="//placehold.it/120x120/69c/9cf/?text=2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```